# Error message if deleting a comment fails is misleading

Tags: bug, comments

I get a "*An error occurred during voting*" error message in a red popup when deleting a comment fails. But that message is misleading as I wasn't voting the comment but deleting it. It should be "*An error occurred during deleting*".

Steps to reproduce:

1. Post a comment, say, 'Blah blah bladdeddy blah!'
2. Disconnect your device from the internet
3. Press the delete button <kbd>X</kbd> next to the comment
4. You get "*An error occurred during voting*" which is misleading